# Angular5 - Intercept change a public property in static service

Tags: angular, typescript, service, angular5

Consider following `Angular` service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
     public userConnected: UserManageInfo;
     getManageInfo(): Observable<UserManageInfo> {

       return this.httpClient
        .get('api/Account/ManageInfo', { headers: this.getCustomHeaders() })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            if (error.status == 401)
                return this.logout();
            return Observable.throw(error)
        })
        .map((response: any) => {
            this.userConnected = response;
            return this.userConnected;
        });
     }
}
```

`getManageInfo()` is invoked from `app.component.ts`.
In addition, the constructor of another `AppSidebarComponent` component should get this information on application start up.

Currently I do it this way:

```
export class AppSidebarComponent implements OnInit {
    public currentUser: UserManageInfo = new UserManageInfo();

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
          this.currentUser = this.authService.userConnected;
    }
}
```

However if the property changes the `currentUser` property of `AppSidebarComponent` is not getting updated .

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: where is the subscription to the observable happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases like that it's common to use BehaviorSubject from rxjs:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
     public UserConnected = new BehaviorSubject<UserManageInfo>(null); // create it and initialise will null, for example

     getManageInfo(): Observable<UserManageInfo> {
       return this.httpClient
        .get('api/Account/ManageInfo', { headers: this.getCustomHeaders() })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            if (error.status == 401)
                return this.logout();
            return Observable.throw(error)
        })
        .do(response => this.UserConnected.next(response)); // make sure you subscribe to this observable somewhere so that it's executed
     }
}
```

Then in your component:

```
export class AppSidebarComponent implements OnInit {
    public CurrentUser: UserManageInfo = new UserManageInfo();

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        this.authService.UserConnected.subscribe((data: UserManageInfo) => {
            this.CurrentUser = data;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, glad to help! Could you mark the answer as accepted so that other users would know that it's a working solution?